"\deleted" doesn't support "\autoref" in "changes" package in LaTeX
With changes package, the \deleted command doesn't support \autoref command, but \added does. What is the reason?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq1}
    a+b=c
\end{equation}
\added{\autoref{eq1}}
\deleted{hello\autoref{eq1}}

\end{document}


The error is
\UL@stop ...z@ \else \UL@putbox \fi \else \egroup 
                                                  \egroup \UL@putbox \fi \if...
l.10 \deleted{hello\autoref{eq1}}
                                 
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.


You can reduce it down to loading soul and hyperref, \sout{\autoref{eq1}} gives the same error.

@daleif Is there a way to solve it?

Not sure, you need alternatives to soul (it is rather fragile), and then you need to tell the changes package to use the alternative

If you can live with \autoref never being hyphenated you can use \hbox{\autoref{eq1}} that compiles.

@daleif This is the only effective method currently.
